# Laravel 5.5 & Vue.js Blade Testing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following in my blade...

```
<div>
  <contact-form></contact-form>
</div>
```

I want to test to ensure that the Vue.js component  is always mounted in my tests...

```
public function testRoute()
{
    $this->visit('/');
    //stuck here
}
```

Basically I'mm looking forward to testing that the blade has `<contact-form>`. How should I proceed?

Comment: did you try returning view  `return view('YourView');`

Comment: @MeeraTank am running feature tests not coding the actual features

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI `<contact-form></contact-form>` doesn't seem like a valid html markup for me. So validating against it seems like bad practice. Proof me if I'm wrong....

Comment: @Bart I believe the op is using a vue component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: @adam thanks for pointing that out. I'm not into Vue so much... But on the other hand, is Dusk capable of handling all the Vue markups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `assertSee`

> Assert that the given string is contained within the response

```
$this
    ->visit('/')
    ->assertSee('<contact-form>')
    ->assertSee('</contact-form>');
```

See more laravel 5.5 testing assertions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/http-tests)

Or if you want to get deeper into client side browser testing look at [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk), it has `assertSourceHas` method.

Comment: +1 because `assertSourceHas` will look at the unrendered html. `<contact-form>` will no longer look like that after being rendered by Vue / react / angular / ... which is probably key in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `call` or `get` method from `MakesHttpRequests.php` trait to inspect the text:

```
// this returns \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse
$response = $this->get('/');
// use the TestResponse api
$response->assertSee($value);
```

Github source code reference:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php